# custom function not returning results of for loop from magicfor

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that runs kmeans clustering on a specific columns within a dataset and returns the cluster membership. The idea is that someone else could say "what would the clustering look like if I used columns x,y, and z".

I'm trying to use the following code. For some reason, the magic_result() won't return anything when I put it into the function.

```
mydata.test <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), b = 
c(2,2,2,4,4,4,5,5,5), c = c(1,1,1,6,6,6,4,4,4), d = 
c(1,1,1,4,4,4,2,2,2), e = c(14,40,84,14,40,84,14,40,84))
mylist.test <- list(c(1,2),c(2,3),c(1,2,3),c(1,2,5))

magic_free()
my.kmeans.test <- function(myd,myk,myl) { 
    library(magicfor)
    magic_for(print,silent=T)
    for(i in myl) {
        kmeans <- kmeans(myd[,i],centers=myk,nstart=25)
        cl <- kmeans$cluster
        print(cl)
    }
    res <- magic_result()
    res.cl <- res$cl
    return(res.cl)
}
```

What I don't understand is that when I try to run this as just a for loop (rather than a function) it works.

```
library(magicfor)
magic_for(print,silent=T)
for(i in myl) {
  kmeans <- kmeans(mydata.test[,i],centers=3,nstart=25)
  cl <- kmeans$cluster
  print(cl)
}
res <- magic_result()
res.cl <- res$cl
res.cl
```

I'm guessing there's something funky going on with magicfor. Any idea how to get around this? Anything is appreciated.

Comment: And it's a requirement to use the `magicfor` library? that just seems dangerous. Are you open to using more functional-friendly solutions like the `purrr` library?

Comment: @MrFlick thanks so much! Definitely not a requirement to use magicfor, just need something that will let me save the results from the loop (rather than just printing them). Any idea how to do this with purrr? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` from `purrr`, you can just do

```
library(purrr)
my.kmeans.test <- function(myd, myk, myl) { 
  map(myl, function(idx) {
    kmeans(myd[, idx], centers=myk, nstart=25)$center
  })
}

my.kmeans.test(mydata.test, 3, mylist.test)
```

Comment: you're a lifesaver